# Vue v-on:click triggers unknown custom element error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**What happens?**

Vuejs instead of treating v-on:click / @click as an event handler it treats it as if I was adding a  element. And triggers the following error

```
vue.common.js:593 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <click> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <OrderTable> at resources\assets\js\components\OrderTable\OrderTable.vue
       <Page> at resources\assets\js\components\Pages\Page.vue
         <Root>
warn @ vue.common.js:593
createElm @ vue.common.js:5570
addVnodes @ vue.common.js:5737
updateChildren @ vue.common.js:5864
patchVnode @ vue.common.js:5938
updateChildren @ vue.common.js:5824
patchVnode @ vue.common.js:5938
updateChildren @ vue.common.js:5824
patchVnode @ vue.common.js:5938
patch @ vue.common.js:6098
Vue._update @ vue.common.js:2672
updateComponent @ vue.common.js:2790
get @ vue.common.js:3144
run @ vue.common.js:3221
flushSchedulerQueue @ vue.common.js:2983
(anonymous) @ vue.common.js:1839
flushCallbacks @ vue.common.js:1760
```

I have simplified the component the error is happening in. But there is nothing special about the `span` that is triggering the error. It's a child of the root `div` element. Also the `addRow` method is irrelevant as the error happens no matter which function you bind to the click event.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <span v-on:click="addRow">Add new row</span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "OrderTable",
    methods: {
    newRow: function () {
        console.log('Adding new row')
    },
}
```

This is the extract from app.js regarding the element:

```
_c("span", { on: { click: _vm.newRow } }, [_vm._v("Add new row")])
```

Comment: You are trying to run addRow method on click event, but in methods you have newRow method

Comment: Is this `OrderTable.vue` file? if not then can you share that file?

Comment: @click="addRow"

Comment: try to change the name of the event, e.g. `blur`, or add another event handler before this `<span @blur="newRow" @click="newRow">` and see what the new error is ?

Comment: @VladislavLadicky thanks, but that was a mistake I made "reducing" the code to post it here, in the original code the handler function name matches.